# Creating a relation with ASPNetUsers table and custom

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to make a relation with ASPNETUsers table and my custom table. ASPNetUsers will contain users who register and then Admin can chose from the list of Users and pick a User which will then become a employee. I didnt implement any logic to that yet because I dont know how to connect those tables. Im not looking for done code I just cant figure out how to connect this two.

[image: This is te structure of my DB]

[image: This is my soluton structure]

On photos above you can see my DB and solution structure. 
AlgebraSchoolApp is MVC app with individual users accounts login. 
Entities contatin my models which are added in ApplicationDbContext inside AlgebraSchoolApp. 
DAL is just used for accesing data from DB (update,edit,delete functions).

Comment: I assume this is database-first and not code-first?

Comment: Its code-first approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `IdentityModels.cs` located at `ProjectName > Models > IdentityModels.cs`. Navigate to the `ApplicationUser` class.

From there you could add custom properties. Since you are using code-first, Entity Framework will automatically map the property for you when you `update-database` just be sure to supply the data annotation

```
ForeignKey("PropertyName")
```

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int? EmployeeId{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public Employee Employee{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerdine Sabio that worked like a charm! 
Do you have any guides for stuff like this? I found a lot of internet things I search to be confusing.

Comment: @brika28 Sorry, I really don't have save any guides. Usually stackoverflow provide me what I need, I just need to be specific with the search term. For example, the search term for this specific question is "aspnetusers custom property". Thanks, and good luck with the project!

Comment: I'd do it the other way around. Rather not touch the ASP.Net Identity model.